# How does strings’ immutability help in string interning?

Tags: c#, string, immutability

[An answer to this question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1158680.aspx?In+C+why+are+strings+immutable+) mentions that the `immutable` characteristic of `string` helps in achieving **string interning**.

Can anyone please explain how the characteristic of being **immutable** helps in achieving **interning**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `String` were a mutable type, it simply couldn't be interned. There's no point in keeping a pool of objects if they can be mutated... you wouldn't be able to rely on what you got out of the pool being the string you were interested in (at least by the time you used it).

Imagine:

```
string x = "foo";
string y = "foo";
// x and y are references to the same object...

x.MutateTo("bar"); // This doesn't change which object y refers to...
Console.WriteLine(y); // This would have to print "bar" - eek!
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings with the same value can *refer* to the same interned string object. If you could change an interned string, the change would be reflected everywhere that interned string was used. Something like:

```
string foo = "bats";
string bar = "bats";

foo[0] = 'c';

Console.WriteLine(bar); // cats
```

Of course, they could be un-interned on write, but why bother? To do that, there’s effectively one option, slightly improved by adding a bunch of compiler special cases that aren’t worth it: override the subscripting operator for strings and make sure every mutating method un-interns the string, effectively turning strings into `List<char>` with extra overhead. Strings are used a lot; this could be a bit slow.

The copying necessary to un-intern means there’s no performance benefit compared to passing the string to `StringBuilder` or `List<char>`. As for readability and ease of understanding: explicit is better than implicit.